# My netbook is running slowly

Tags: 14.04

My laptop configuration is:

- ASPIRE ONE D255E
- CPU Intel Atom ( 1.66GHz, 512Kb cache)
- Memory (1 GB DDR3 Memory)
- Storage ( 250 GB HDD )

I am running Ubuntu 14.4 LTS 32Bit. When I cold boot my netbook, it doesn't start correctly. Then I press the power button for a while to turn off it then start again.

When I start google chrome it takes a long time to do anything. Beside that, during installation of any software, the computer has a slow response time as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you convert your system to Lubuntu, as your computer's specs aren't very good for running the full Ubuntu Unity desktop.

Lubuntu is the lightweight variant of Ubuntu, using LXDE as the default desktop. You can convert your system to Lubuntu by running this in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

Afterwards, reboot, and you should end up with a different login screen and UI, but the same preferences across your applications.

Comment: I think this answer totally should do it - except OP's harddisk has bad blocks.

Comment: Where in the question does it say that the hard disk has bad blocks? The booting up issue only happened once, and was probably just a minor issue.

Comment: Where does it state that it happend only once?
In my experience a dying harddisk can be a symptom for a slow os.
Or was it vice versa?
Anyways, it ain't a bad idea to check for that 2!